# Expanding a macro into quotes in `m4`

Tags: m4

In `m4`, is it possible to expand a macro and to immediately put it in quotes? That is, instead of

```
define(HELLO, `Hello!')dnl
define(MACRO, `HELLO')dnl
MACRO
```

expanding to `Hello!`, I would love to have some function `qexpand`, for example, such that

```
define(HELLO, `Hello!')dnl
define(MACRO, `HELLO')dnl
qexpand(`MACRO')
```

expands to `HELLO`. But any other line after the first two that expands `MACRO` into a string would do as well, of course.

---

*Background*. I want to operate substitutions on the expansion of a macro using `patsubst`, say substituting commas in it. Unfortunately

```
define(`MACRO',`x,y,z')dnl
patsubst(`MACRO',`,',`.')
```

yields `x,y,z`, as the substitution is performed on the string `MACRO`. But if the expansion of the macro contains commas, the variant

```
define(`MACRO',`x,y,z')dnl
patsubst(MACRO,`,',`.')
```

has the second line first expand to `` patsubst(x,y,z,`,',`.') ``, giving the error `` Warning: excess arguments to builtin `patsubst' ignored ``. The possibility of expanding a macro into quotes would solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defn()` is your `qexpand()` function.

```
define(HELLO, `Hello!')dnl
define(MACRO, `HELLO')dnl
defn(`MACRO')
```

would output `HELLO`, and

```
define(`MACRO',`x,y,z')dnl
patsubst(defn(`MACRO'),`,',`.')
```

would output `x.y.z`.

`defn()` returns the quoted definition of each of its arguments.  In the second example above, we use it to get the quoted string `x,y,z` (the quoted value of `MACRO`).  This is then handed over to `patsubst` which will change the commas into dots.

[The POSIX standard for `m4`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/m4.html) has this to say about this macro:

> `defn`
>
> The defining text of the `defn` macro shall be the quoted definition (using the current quoting strings) of its arguments. The behavior is unspecified if defn is not immediately followed by a `<left-parenthesis>`.

For BSD `m4`, the `defn()` macro [is documented](https://man.openbsd.org/m4) as

> `defn(name, ...)`
>
> Returns the quoted definition for each argument.  This can
>                     be used to rename macro definitions (even for built-in
>                     macros).

GNU `m4` has (in the [`m4` `info` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.18/html_node/Defn.html#Defn)),

> Builtin: `defn (NAME...)`
>
> Expands to the *quoted definition* of each `NAME`.  If an argument
>        is not a defined macro, the expansion for that argument is empty.
>
> If `NAME` is a user-defined macro, the quoted definition is simply
>        the quoted expansion text.  If, instead, there is only one `NAME`
>        and it is a builtin, the expansion is a special token, which
>        points to the builtin's internal definition.  This token is only
>        meaningful as the second argument to `define` (and `pushdef`), and
>        is silently converted to an empty string in most other contexts.
>        Combining a builtin with anything else is not supported; a warning
>        is issued and the builtin is omitted from the final expansion.
>
> The macro `defn` is recognized only with parameters.